# Test Code Still Only at 0% Coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, scheduled-apex

I've written a test code for a class which I thought would be just about 100% coverage - but it's still showing only 0% in the class after the test runs. The class itself is running correctly.

Here is the class :

```
public class WeeklyMailerOpp_A implements Schedulable
{
    public void execute (SchedulableContext scx)
    {
        List<Wealth__c> recordsA = [
            SELECT No_IXI_Relationship__c, Relationship_HHAge__c, Name, OwnerId, Distributed__c,Solicitable__c,Code_Targeted__c,Division_Letter__c FROM Wealth__c
            WHERE Distributed__c = false AND Solicitable__c = True AND Code_Targeted__c = 'Yes' AND Relationship_HHAge__c >= 25 AND No_IXI_Relationship__c != True AND Division_Letter__c = 'A' LIMIT 25   
        ];

        List<Wealth__c> recordsB = [
            SELECT No_IXI_Relationship__c, Relationship_HHAge__c, Name, OwnerId, Distributed__c,Solicitable__c,Code_Targeted__c,Division_Letter__c FROM Wealth__c
            WHERE Distributed__c = false AND Solicitable__c = True AND Code_Targeted__c = 'Yes' AND Relationship_HHAge__c >= 25 AND No_IXI_Relationship__c != True AND Division_Letter__c = 'B' LIMIT 25   
        ];

       for(Wealth__c recordA : recordsA)
        {
            recordA.Distributed__c = true;  
            recordA.Distribution_Date__c = date.TODAY();         
        }

       for(Wealth__c recordB : recordsB)
        {
            recordB.Distributed__c = true;  
            recordB.Distribution_Date__c = date.TODAY();         
        }

        update recordsA;
        update recordsB;

    }
}
```

...and here is the test code :

```
    @isTest
    private class TestWeeklyMailerOpp_A
    {    
        static testMethod void UnitTestWeeklyMailerOpp_A()
        {     

**String cronExpr = '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2022';
    Test.StartTest();
    System.schedule('myJobTestJobName', cronExpr, new WeeklyMailerOpp_A());**   

            Wealth__c mailerA = new Wealth__c();
            mailerA.Distributed__c = False; 
            mailerA.Account__c = '001i000000dmNHI'; 
            mailerA.Code__c = '33';  
            mailerA.Division__c = 'aCX31000000PAuE';      

            Wealth__c mailerB = new Wealth__c();
            mailerB.Distributed__c = False;  
            mailerB.Account__c = '001i000000XmrUI';
            mailerB.Code__c = '33';  
            mailerB.Division__c = 'aCX31000000PAuJ'; 

            insert mailerA;
            insert mailerB;

            List<Wealth__c> recordsA = [
                SELECT Name, OwnerId, Solicitable__c,Distributed__c,Code_Targeted__c,Division_Letter__c FROM Wealth__c
                WHERE Distributed__c = false AND Solicitable__c = True AND Code_Targeted__c = 'Yes' AND Division_Letter__c = 'A' LIMIT 10   
            ];    

            for(Wealth__c recordA : recordsA)
            {
                recordA.Distributed__c = true;  
                recordA.Distribution_Date__c = date.TODAY();         
            }

             List<Wealth__c> recordsB = [
                SELECT Name, OwnerId, Distributed__c,Code_Targeted__c,Division_Letter__c FROM Wealth__c
                WHERE Distributed__c = false AND Solicitable__c = True AND Code_Targeted__c = 'Yes' AND Division_Letter__c = 'B' LIMIT 10   
            ];    

            for(Wealth__c recordB : recordsB)
            {
                recordB.Distributed__c = true;  
                recordB.Distribution_Date__c = date.TODAY();         
            }

            update recordsA;
            update recordsB;  

 **Test.stopTest();**                   
        }    
    }
```

I must be doing something seriously wrong but I can't figure out what. Any ideas ?

Comment: Well, you're not calling your class in your test method.

Comment: @MartinLezer - I made changes. That's now at 49%. Can you tell me what I'm not covering ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never actually run the job. You need to either run it by calling `system.schedule` or calling the `execute` method directly.

Comment: Yha, I suppose that would help, wouldn't it ? I just added some lines to the test code. I am now getting 49% coverage. While 49% is much better than 0% it's not quite what I wanted. Can you see what I am not covering ? The lines I added are within the asterisk. Thank you.

Comment: @Zoom_v That's kind of a completely different question! Also your edits to the question didn't really make clear what's not covered, but the only lines which wouldn't get covered are those inside the `for` loops. In other words, your queries didn't return data.

Comment: You're right - different question. Thanks @Adrian.